# Modifying controls for an MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there a way to modify the control set for an MPMoviePlayerController? I really only want to keep around the fullscreen icon.

Comment: There is no clean one - none that does not risk app-store rejection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.  You could just disable the controls and make the fullscreen button yourself though, no?  It would be very trivial.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. It's unfortunate there isn't a built in way to accomplish this.